# Method analysis using Reflection and CodeDom

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, code-analysis, codedom

The context of this question is too elaborate to describe here and will likely adversely affect responses so I am not including it. I want to assert certain things about a method in a unit test. Some of these things are possible using reflection such as format of the `try/finally` block, class fields and method local variables, etc. I already know the type and method signature.

```
    protected override void OnTest ()
    {
        bool result = false;
        SomeCOMObject com = null; // System.__ComObject

        try
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(com);
        }

        return (result);
    }
```

What I have not been able to achieve are things like:

- Whether the method contains only a single `return (result);` statement and whether that statement is the last one in the function.
- Whether all variables of type `System.__ComObject` have been manually de-referenced using `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(object)` in the `finally` block.

Since some of these things are not possible using reflection, and source code text analysis is far from ideal, I turned to CodeDom but have not been able to get a grip on it. I have been told that creating expression trees from source code is not possible. Nor is it possible to create expression trees from the runtime type. If that is correct, how can I leverage CodeDom to achieve things in the list above?

I have used CodeDom in the past for code generation and compiling simple code classes to assemblies. But I have no idea how it could be used to analyze the internals of a method. Please advise.

Comment: You may want to investigate the Roslyn CTP: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34685

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, reflection built into programming languages provides no access to the content of functions.  So you pretty much can't do this with reflection.

You might be able to do it if you have access to the byte-code equivalent, but byte code can't really answer questions about the *syntax* of the method, e.g., "how many return statements exists returning the same expression".

If you want to reason about code, your need to reason about the *source* code.   This means you need access to a parser, and often other useful facts ("what the declaration of X?", "Is the type of X and Y compatible?", "Does data flow from X to Y?"), etc.

Roslyn provides some of this information.  There are also commercial solutions (I have one).

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct in understanding that CodeDom, Roslyn and other commercial solutions operate on the same principal of exposing compiler types and services? I would also be interested in knowing which solution you use since I am researching on what to go with for the long-term.

Comment: My company offers the DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit, which is explicitly designed to offer services supporting parsing, name resolution, flow analysis, source code transformation, etc. for many computer languages, to varying degrees depending on customer interest and previous applications. Your specific question for C# ("Does the method contain just 1 return, and is the last statement?" can be answered quite easily with DMS's C# AST.   See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html

Comment: thank you. Perhaps someone from your sales team could educate me on the product and what it offers beyond CodeCom and Roslyn. If so, please feel free to use my profile contact info.